# Handling sequentials http calls with RxJS and get response as soon as it arrives

Tags: node.js, ajax, rxjs

I'm trying to write a JS service that will potentially send a number of calls to an external API at the same time and, as the API is rate limited, I want to stagger the calls and handle the responses **separately**.

I could use `concatMap` or `mergeMap` (with the concurrency option) but I have no idea how to handle the responses like I mentioned.

If `service A`, `service B` and `service C` tell the *HTTP service* to send 3 separate requests, I need the function in `service A` to get the first answer in its own pipe.

http.js:

```
let subscribe;
const observable$ = Observable.create((sub) => {
    subscribe = sub;
});

function generateRequest(ajaxParams){
    subscribe.next(ajaxParams);
}

observable$
    .pipe(
        mergeMap((params) => {
           return ajax(params);
        }, response => response, 2)
    )
    .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

`observable$` being the stream where I send the http params and the pipe handles the ajax instantiation and the delays/concurrency.

So my question is, how would I do something like this:

serviceA.js:

```
generateRequest(ajaxParams).pipe(map(response => response.data), tap((data) => {
    console.log('Here is the data', data);
})).subscribe(() => {})
```

Comment: Are you sending the request from node or the browser?

Comment: @AdrianBrand From node

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by combining all of your Observables without subscribing to them first, as demonstrated below:

```js
const service_A_Observable = generateRequest(ajaxParams)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.data),
    tap((data) => {
     // handle stream here...
    })
  );

const service_B_Observable = generateRequest(ajaxParams)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.data),
    tap((data) => {
        // handle stream here...
    })
  );

from([service_A_Observable, service_B_Observable]).pipe(concatMap(obs => obs)).subscribe();
```

Or optionally customizing the desired concurrency:

```js
from([...]).pipe(mergeMap(o => o, MAX_PARALLEL)).subscribe();
```